# Переопределить мок-объект

Tags: юнит-тесты, php, phpunit

В программе один и тот же объект последовательно, от разных аргументов, возвращает разные значения, в зависимости от которых идет ветвление.
В тесте не получается переопределить мок, чтобы во второй вызов он возвращал другой результат. Как быть в такой ситуации?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте `->at()` или собственный коллбек для установленного `expectation'а`:

> - [phpunit mock method multiple calls with different arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5988616/phpunit-mock-method-multiple-calls-with-different-arguments)
> - [How can I get PHPUnit MockObjects to return differernt values based on a parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277914/how-can-i-get-phpunit-mockobjects-to-return-differernt-values-based-on-a-paramet)

Comment: Да, отлично, at() работает.

Пока делал с callBack тоже получилось, но не смог передать в нее параметры. Туда передаются параметры из реальной функции, а как передать параметры из теста?

Comment: @nMike *(имхо)*

- Если писать правильно, то `callback` должен принимать решение только на основании его входных параметров.

- Если же в нем получается какая-то более сложная логика или требуются дополнительные данные, то их стоит выносить в приватные члены тестового класса или создавать вспомогательный объект типа `TestCallbackFactory.

Comment: Ну по логике callback вызывается с параметрами, которые ты ему передаешь. В данном случае твои параметры из теста игнорируются, вместо них появляются параметры из тестируемой функции(т.е. те, которые передаются заглушенному методу при его вызове из тестируемой функции).